# Generate shim `.so` to rename symbols of existing `.so`

Tags: java, linux, openssl, shared-libraries

I have an existing pre-built `.so` shared library (let's call it `libjniopenssl.so`). It was built by third party on `Debian Linux` with `OpenSSL 1.0.1k-3+deb8u4`.
I had to run `libjniopenssl.so` on `CentOS` with `OpenSSL 1.0.2k` package. 
Despite the `OpenSSL` versions are slightly different the API used by `libjniopenssl.so` were not changed between `1.0.1k` and `1.0.2k` - so I expected them to be source and binary compatible for my scenario.
Unfortunately just running `libjniopenssl.so` on `CentOS` does not work.

The `libjniopenssl.so` is loaded by `JVM` via `System.loadLibrary`, but it fails with the following error when running on `CentOS`:

```
Unable to load libjniopenssl: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/jna-112200956/jna6604950569974562639.tmp:
libcrypto.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The reason is simple, there is no such file `libcrypto.so.1.0.0` on `CentOS`, because `OpenSSL 1.0.2k 16.el7` provides only following `.so`'s:

```
$ ls -l /lib64/libcrypto*
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root      19 Jun  5  2018 /lib64/libcrypto.so.10 -> libcrypto.so.1.0.2k
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 2512832 Apr 11  2018 /lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.2k
```

For some reason `CentOS` package [intentionally renamed](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=288863#p288863) `.so` file name from default `libcrypto.so.1.0.0` to `libcrypto.so.1.0.2k`, even so when compiling that version from [source](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/tree/OpenSSL_1_0_2k) it uses name `libcrypto.so.1.0.0`.

This error message suggested to try creating a symlink with name `/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.0` which points to `/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.2k`

This resulted in the following error in run-time:

```
Unable to load libjniopenssl: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/jna-112200956/jna2564265718506275007.tmp: 
/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: version `OPENSSL_1.0.0' not found (required by /tmp/jna-112200956/jna2564265718506275007.tmp)
```

Inspecting `libjniopenssl.so` shown that there are following symbols referenced from `OpenSSL`:

```
$ readelf -Ws libjniopenssl.so

Symbol table '.dynsym' contains 40 entries:
Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
    0: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  UND
    1: 0000000000000e98     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    9
    2: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  WEAK   DEFAULT  UND __gmon_start__
    3: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  WEAK   DEFAULT  UND _Jv_RegisterClasses
    4: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init@OPENSSL_1.0.0 (2)
    5: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND malloc@GLIBC_2.2.5 (3)
    6: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND OPENSSL_add_all_algorithms_noconf@OPENSSL_1.0.0 (2)
    7: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND HMAC_CTX_cleanup@OPENSSL_1.0.0 (2)
    8: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND EVP_CipherUpdate@OPENSSL_1.0.0 (2)
    9: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  WEAK   DEFAULT  UND _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable
    10: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND ERR_load_crypto_strings@OPENSSL_1.0.0 (2)
    11: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND free@GLIBC_2.2.5 (3)
    12: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  WEAK   DEFAULT  UND _ITM_registerTMCloneTable
    13: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    WEAK   DEFAULT  UND __cxa_finalize@GLIBC_2.2.5 (3)
    14: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND HMAC_CTX_init@OPENSSL_1.0.0 (2)
    15: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND HMAC_Final@OPENSSL_1.0.0 (2)
    16: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND EVP_sha1@OPENSSL_1.0.0 (2)
    17: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND HMAC_Init_ex@OPENSSL_1.0.0 (2)
    18: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND HMAC_Update@OPENSSL_1.0.0 (2)
    19: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup@OPENSSL_1.0.0 (2)
    20: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND EVP_MD_size@OPENSSL_1.0.0 (2)
    21: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND EVP_aes_128_ctr@OPENSSL_1.0.1 (4)
```

But the `libcrypto.so.1.0.2k` on `CentOS` has symbols which has different postfix, for example:

```
readelf -Ws /lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.2k | grep -iE "EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init"
705: 000000000012a6b0   151 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   13 EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init@@libcrypto.so.10
```

So, on `CentOS` postfix is `@@libcrypto.so.10`, but `libjniopenssl.so` was linked against shared library which has symbols with postfix `@OPENSSL_1.0.0`. That's probably why just adding symlink does not work.

The further investigation shown that `Debian` version of `OpenSSL 1.0.1k` has [included many patches](https://launchpad.net/debian/+archive/primary/+sourcefiles/openssl/1.0.1k-3+deb8u4/openssl_1.0.1k-3+deb8u4.debian.tar.xz), including one which [adds symbol versioning](https://rt.openssl.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=1222). It was introduced only in `OpenSSL 1.1.0`, but was back ported by someone who is providing Debian package to `1.0.1`.

In contrary `CentOS` `OpenSSL 1.0.2k` package does not include that patch for symbol versioning (but they include other patches from `1.1.0` according to symbols in `.so`).

I could re-build `libjniopenssl.so` on `CentOS` against it's copy of `OpenSSL`, but it actually involving maintaining (building, storing, deploying) own copy of `libjniopenssl.so` which actually comes from third-party git repository. I don't like rebuild solution, so I'm looking for more elegant one. But I have to say that [re-building](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=288863#p288863) is what recommended on `CentOS` forum.

One solution I could think of is generation during build or deploy time a special shim `libcrypto.so.1.0.0` (based on target system-provided copy of `libcrypto`) which has renamed symbols as desired by `libjniopenssl.so`, but under the hood it will translate all calls to the original system-provided `libcrypto.so.1.0.2k`.

In general I'm looking for some tool or set of tools which is capable of automatically generating such a "shim/adapter/proxy" `.so` out of specified "implementation" `.so`, but with ability to redefine some or all symbols.
I've found that there is `objcopy` tool which has `--redefine-symbol old=new`, but it doesn't exactly do what I want: I don't want to copy any code from original `.so`, I do want to translate calls to original "implementation" `.so`.

**UPD**: It is occurred by running local experiment that `objcopy` does not support renaming of symbols in dynamic library. The problem confirmed from this [mail thread](https://sourceware.org/ml/binutils/2006-03/msg00005.html).

Summarizing, my questions are:

1. Is there an existing util capable to generate such shared shim library for a specified `.so` file?
2. Or maybe there is a better way to solve this incompatibility between `CentOS` and `Debian` `OpenSSL` packages, assuming I don't want to modify neither third-party provided `libjniopenssl.so` nor OS provided copy of `OpenSSL`?

Comment: Debian's and CentOS's OpenSSL seem to be binary incompatible. Forcing linkage by renaming symbols can lead to run-time errors.

Comment: There is a good reason they suggest rebuilding it. And it's sound advice that you should follow whether or not it's something you want to do. If they're incompatible don't expect any utility to 'fix' the problem. And remember this in programming: **the appearance of something 'working' does not mean it is correct**. There's a big difference. Incompatibilities are incompatibilities no matter how much you dislike it. In short the answer is you're going about it the wrong way and that's just the way it is.

Comment: @Vi. this is true but in practice simple symlinking is often enough because apps do not call into the incompatible subset of the ABI. I understand that this is risky, incorrect, etc. but this is nevertheless a common practice.

Answer (score 1):

[Implib.so](https://github.com/yugr/Implib.so) is capable of generating shim wrapper for arbitrary .so library. Running

```
$ implib-gen.py --dlopen-callback=mycallback libcrypto.so.1.0.0
```

will generate `libcrypto.so.1.0.0.tramp.S` and `libcrypto.so.1.0.0.init.c` which will implement version-less wrappers over all symbols in `libcrypto.so.1.0.0`. You'll also need a small loader for the OS-specific implementation (that is `libcrypto.so.1.0.2k`):

```
$ cat mycallback.c
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
#endif

// Load OS-specific implementation underneath
void *mycallback(const char *lib_name) {
  void *h = dlmopen(LM_ID_NEWLM, "libcrypto.so.1.0.2k", RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_DEEPBIND);
  if (h)
    return h;
  fprintf(stderr, "dlmopen failed: %s\n", dlerror());
  exit(1);
}
```

Linking you code with autogenerated files, `mycallback.c` and `-ldl` should solve the incompatible version issue.